# Is _write in io.h a blocking call?

Tags: c++, c, microsoft-runtime-library

I've inherited some code which, to initialise some hardware, writes a few bytes and then waits for a return. To do this it calls the `_write` function from `io.h`. From my testing, it looks like it's locking up at that point. So my questions are as follows:

1. Is that function a blocking function?
2. Is there a way of setting a timeout?
3. Is there an alternative non-blocking function I could use instead?

Comment: The standard defines no `_write` in io.h. Perhaps you should use the stream facilities instead, which will buffer things for you? Oh, and I believe the answers are yes, no, and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365683.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do async I/O on Windows then either use the Win32 APIs directly (look at docs for WriteFileEx/ReadFileEx, which contain pointers to general background on async I/O vs sync) or consider boost::asio.

Comment: I don't want async I/O I just need it to time out if there's a problem.

Comment: I guess I could write a callback function which sets a flag when it's done, and a wrapper to wait until that flag is set or timed out..

Comment: That's the kind of thing you have to consider - remembering to correlate and discard pending callbacks after the timeout.  There's no way to even approach this problem with sync I/O as a baseline though. I/O completion ports is the most efficient way to do async I/O on Windows. I gather boost::asio is good but have not used it myself.